# Work-around for Styled-component not working on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11, styled-components

I have styled-components on my web-app.

They work great. Except on Internet Explorer 11. They completely break and the layout is just a pile of components laying there horizontally instead of the flexbox and whatnot.

What is the usual way to work around this problem? Should I somehow recognize in the js code that if the browser is IE11, then I should just use inline-styling or is there some kind of a fix for this issue? I tried googling around but didn't find anything definitive.

EDIT: Further investigation shows that reason is that this is an Angular project. Actually this is an Angular project with a React view in it (yes, I know) And the React view uses styled-components which work great on other browsers but our customer uses only IE11 so we have to work around this or just ditch the styled components altogether.

Answer (score 0):

There was a great issue on this a while ago: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/657

Please note that the code there is out of date and the solution is questionable since it might break other guarantees.

However, the solution either lies in stopping other libraries from unmounting or mutating styled-components style nodes, or changing them so that they’re slightly more resilient to change.

If you don’t use SSR, we have an API coming soon that allows you to specify a custom DOM element to mount style tags into using the StyleSheetManager. You can try it using the “dev” tag on npm.

Other than that you can modify our code so that we do not mount elements into the document head.

Answer (score 0):

### 2020 Update:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59044410/2077884

Apparently there is a package called `react-app-polyfill` that helps with this. I wasn't able to get `styled-components/macro` working on an old TV without installing `react-app-polyfill`.

`core-js` and `regenerator-runtime` and `@babel/polyfill` and `raf` polyfills did not seem to fix it for me.