# create-react-app keeps post-ES5 JavaScript

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, ecmascript-5

I am using the TypeScript flavor of create-react-app:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --typescript
```

When I build the app, the bundle still includes post-ES5 code such as Symbol. What am I missing? My tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that create-react-app has an associated polyfill package called react-app-polyfill, [not included in the solution by default](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/supported-browsers-features/).

Setting the target to ES5 is not enough, you also need to [get the polyfill package](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-app-polyfill/README.md) and reference it in the code. For example for IE11 support:

```
// This must be the first line in src/index.js
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
```